# Add Interactive Map with Highcharts Maps

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am a beginning developer trying to implement interactive maps with JavaScript using Highcharts Maps (http://www.highcharts.com/products/highmaps).

I have managed to produce a basic map of Haiti. Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/mattbowlby/P8KZQ/2/

I put the JavaScript for the map in a file called haiti.js. This is the content of that file:

```
$(function () {

    // Initiate the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('Map', { 
        series: [ 
    { 
        "type": "map",
        "data": [
      {
        "name": "Ouest",
        "path": "M587,-486L584,-485L578,-494L575,-496L564,-497L533,-504L522,-505L511,-507L479,-527L448,-535L440,-541L432,-551L426,-555L421,-560L418,-568L419,-572L423,-577L429,-581L436,-584L444,-585L452,-584L501,-564L526,-557L553,-543L578,-533L588,-521L591,-513L592,-503L591,-494ZM896,-428L909,-415L902,-420L896,-428ZM950,-485L944,-479L937,-466L933,-461L919,-456L893,-461L880,-458L875,-454L873,-468L869,-474L859,-465L855,-454L856,-441L865,-428L884,-419L887,-412L890,-409L898,-409L910,-413L913,-406L908,-402L907,-398L909,-391L914,-389L928,-385L931,-383L940,-372L953,-363L972,-356L981,-349L977,-342L946,-336L928,-347L904,-348L874,-348L844,-354L813,-360L783,-357L754,-359L744,-370L734,-369L718,-377L705,-377L694,-372L685,-361L669,-354L656,-353L652,-349L638,-348L630,-341L624,-341L619,-344L616,-334L612,-331L609,-326L597,-329L585,-332L575,-325L568,-328L564,-334L553,-335L536,-331L532,-339L526,-346L521,-353L518,-362L512,-368L503,-368L502,-378L508,-387L505,-396L530,-401L561,-394L559,-388L575,-392L581,-393L587,-390L612,-386L625,-390L635,-398L642,-409L647,-423L656,-433L667,-436L726,-431L729,-436L733,-436L743,-426L746,-424L753,-426L755,-432L756,-440L755,-463L756,-467L762,-478L757,-485L741,-492L728,-493L724,-494L716,-500L710,-508L703,-513L694,-512L682,-519L676,-529L658,-557L646,-568L638,-572L626,-577L631,-583L637,-588L660,-587L694,-583L703,-583L711,-573L729,-565L738,-559L747,-550L756,-538L768,-531L780,-528L791,-521L812,-500L839,-492L867,-501L895,-507L919,-499L934,-495L947,-488Z"
      },
      {
        "name": "Grand'Anse",
        "path": "M273,-447L265,-442L253,-442L245,-447L244,-457L252,-461L264,-460L273,-455ZM13,-357L12,-365L9,-370L0,-382L12,-400L10,-405L16,-409L20,-427L25,-430L26,-437L22,-448L25,-451L37,-458L52,-465L59,-466L71,-464L74,-470L82,-471L102,-470L116,-467L162,-447L182,-446L187,-439L193,-441L208,-434L224,-434L232,-431L239,-425L245,-423L250,-426L258,-424L264,-425L261,-419L255,-412L257,-407L263,-404L255,-396L249,-381L226,-375L210,-375L205,-367L206,-359L189,-360L172,-364L157,-369L142,-373L107,-370L52,-358L33,-356L23,-358Z"
      },
      {
        "name": "Nord-Ouest",
        "path": "M601,-992L634,-979L649,-971L645,-962L639,-964L609,-968L596,-973L579,-977L573,-979L561,-976L545,-980L537,-984L532,-989L537,-991L553,-997L570,-999L580,-1000L587,-999ZM633,-896L622,-897L608,-888L601,-886L579,-867L553,-862L538,-864L524,-865L510,-869L496,-867L480,-850L478,-828L472,-824L468,-823L455,-827L447,-832L443,-836L436,-829L421,-827L387,-828L377,-830L368,-838L360,-843L356,-863L368,-883L370,-887L373,-887L392,-896L392,-898L372,-898L378,-903L399,-903L441,-923L453,-933L460,-942L465,-937L469,-936L479,-937L493,-933L504,-933L516,-936L527,-934L530,-930L533,-936L539,-940L547,-941L554,-938L563,-942L575,-945L586,-947L597,-946L633,-938L649,-930L670,-924L671,-922L668,-920L663,-910L652,-900L639,-904L634,-903Z"
      },
      {
        "name": "Sud",
        "path": "M281,-264L283,-262L287,-265L293,-259L310,-259L317,-258L322,-255L322,-250L318,-247L311,-246L297,-247L291,-248L285,-251L276,-259L278,-263ZM523,-294L494,-297L482,-296L468,-304L421,-311L400,-309L397,-310L399,-314L404,-316L416,-316L416,-319L393,-321L364,-320L356,-318L344,-311L337,-312L332,-321L327,-318L322,-305L315,-308L311,-305L307,-307L306,-312L307,-318L302,-316L298,-306L293,-302L294,-312L298,-320L288,-311L282,-312L281,-307L266,-295L240,-283L234,-277L228,-267L243,-251L247,-238L246,-235L242,-234L218,-234L211,-236L207,-244L184,-276L179,-279L177,-284L170,-290L136,-315L130,-318L119,-320L110,-325L108,-332L99,-334L87,-339L85,-337L78,-339L64,-331L56,-329L49,-330L35,-337L29,-345L15,-351L13,-357L23,-358L33,-356L52,-358L107,-370L142,-373L157,-369L172,-364L189,-360L206,-359L205,-367L210,-375L226,-375L249,-381L260,-380L272,-380L285,-375L293,-382L304,-383L314,-383L320,-377L325,-371L333,-367L326,-353L344,-348L367,-352L378,-353L389,-353L402,-357L413,-361L431,-359L450,-359L468,-357L476,-360L485,-358L498,-347L509,-337L513,-321L522,-308L524,-295Z"
      },
      {
        "name": "Nippes",
        "path": "M264,-425L276,-436L285,-437L305,-442L318,-439L318,-433L311,-428L302,-429L302,-427L287,-430L281,-429L273,-427L281,-422L287,-421L289,-413L295,-410L306,-412L312,-409L324,-416L339,-418L395,-415L402,-413L416,-406L424,-405L452,-406L466,-405L479,-400L491,-395L496,-394L505,-396L508,-387L502,-378L503,-368L512,-368L518,-362L521,-353L526,-346L525,-335L521,-325L522,-308L513,-321L509,-337L498,-347L485,-358L476,-360L468,-357L450,-359L431,-359L413,-361L402,-357L389,-353L378,-353L367,-352L344,-348L326,-353L333,-367L325,-371L320,-377L314,-383L304,-383L293,-382L285,-375L272,-380L260,-380L249,-381L255,-396L263,-404L257,-407L255,-412L261,-419Z"
      },
      {
        "name": "L'Artibonite",
        "path": "M626,-577L626,-578L588,-617L586,-626L601,-632L615,-633L622,-636L625,-641L623,-648L618,-652L606,-658L602,-662L593,-677L591,-683L597,-691L603,-703L607,-705L618,-707L622,-706L617,-716L613,-718L606,-719L602,-722L600,-729L602,-741L608,-737L614,-736L618,-739L616,-754L621,-754L629,-749L633,-749L626,-763L623,-764L605,-765L600,-769L592,-779L586,-784L563,-794L544,-805L532,-809L519,-819L514,-818L492,-826L478,-828L480,-850L496,-867L510,-869L524,-865L538,-864L553,-862L579,-867L601,-886L608,-888L622,-897L633,-896L637,-887L644,-882L646,-873L653,-875L660,-869L657,-857L662,-850L670,-847L675,-832L681,-817L691,-808L702,-800L715,-794L725,-798L725,-808L732,-807L738,-814L744,-814L756,-809L758,-785L772,-773L786,-766L792,-753L791,-743L792,-732L799,-722L802,-712L787,-689L785,-662L795,-653L791,-645L792,-636L795,-625L790,-606L794,-578L789,-566L788,-555L780,-550L763,-551L747,-550L738,-559L729,-565L711,-573L703,-583L694,-583L660,-587L637,-588L631,-583Z"
      },
      {
        "name": "Centre",
        "path": "M961,-706L973,-695L1000,-682L999,-660L997,-654L993,-647L976,-633L966,-619L951,-601L946,-598L928,-593L922,-589L923,-583L938,-587L947,-587L950,-584L955,-574L969,-560L971,-553L972,-538L975,-523L975,-516L971,-503L967,-496L962,-492L950,-485L947,-488L934,-495L919,-499L895,-507L867,-501L839,-492L812,-500L791,-521L780,-528L768,-531L756,-538L747,-550L763,-551L780,-550L788,-555L789,-566L794,-578L790,-606L795,-625L792,-636L791,-645L795,-653L785,-662L787,-689L802,-712L813,-708L821,-701L824,-696L831,-697L855,-712L880,-726L892,-719L906,-713L912,-707L930,-705L936,-705L949,-705Z"
      },
      {
        "name": "Nord-Est",
        "path": "M961,-706L949,-705L936,-705L930,-705L912,-707L906,-713L892,-719L880,-726L874,-745L856,-762L843,-766L846,-771L847,-781L841,-791L837,-801L832,-810L831,-819L832,-829L842,-833L849,-844L850,-858L853,-864L860,-860L866,-861L870,-866L874,-867L881,-872L891,-873L908,-868L917,-867L920,-865L918,-860L911,-857L901,-857L905,-851L911,-850L923,-853L933,-845L936,-852L936,-854L928,-856L924,-862L927,-868L940,-866L955,-866L960,-849L959,-833L961,-825L971,-802L976,-773L976,-757L970,-746L966,-735L951,-724L953,-717Z"
      },
      {
        "name": "Nord",
        "path": "M880,-726L855,-712L831,-697L824,-696L821,-701L813,-708L802,-712L799,-722L792,-732L791,-743L792,-753L786,-766L772,-773L758,-785L756,-809L744,-814L738,-814L732,-807L725,-808L725,-798L715,-794L702,-800L691,-808L681,-817L675,-832L670,-847L662,-850L657,-857L660,-869L653,-875L646,-873L644,-882L637,-887L633,-896L634,-903L639,-904L652,-900L663,-910L668,-920L671,-922L679,-913L688,-907L698,-904L703,-907L720,-900L730,-898L735,-899L737,-893L754,-878L754,-875L747,-878L753,-865L761,-864L759,-868L764,-873L759,-873L761,-878L759,-883L766,-880L773,-879L780,-882L786,-891L793,-891L798,-887L795,-878L801,-875L807,-874L820,-877L826,-875L831,-870L835,-869L847,-869L853,-864L850,-858L849,-844L842,-833L832,-829L831,-819L832,-810L837,-801L841,-791L847,-781L846,-771L843,-766L856,-762L874,-745Z"
      },
      {
        "name": "Sud-Est",
        "path": "M522,-308L521,-325L525,-335L526,-346L532,-339L536,-331L553,-335L564,-334L568,-328L575,-325L585,-332L597,-329L609,-326L612,-331L616,-334L619,-344L624,-341L630,-341L638,-348L652,-349L656,-353L669,-354L685,-361L694,-372L705,-377L718,-377L734,-369L744,-370L754,-359L783,-357L813,-360L844,-354L874,-348L904,-348L928,-347L946,-336L977,-342L962,-314L959,-307L959,-297L963,-286L965,-265L964,-259L960,-247L954,-251L928,-283L918,-292L905,-300L877,-309L865,-315L854,-319L840,-319L812,-314L775,-313L724,-312L696,-307L685,-312L683,-310L685,-296L682,-292L678,-292L663,-297L621,-292L613,-293L615,-285L605,-288L596,-282L576,-283L567,-279L557,-285L545,-289L531,-293L523,-294L524,-295Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]    
    });
});
```

Now, I am having trouble listing this on my webpage. I have put the JavaScript code into a file titled "haiti.js". I have added the CSS code to my CSS file.

**What HTML do I need to add to my HTML file to display the map?**

This is the contents of my HTML file (maps.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
    <script src="js/haiti.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the content of my CSS file:

```
#container {
  height: 500px; 
  width: 500px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
}
.loading {
  margin-top: 10em;
  text-align: center;
  color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Have you added a script tag to the html file referencing the javascript? Also, open up the console, what does it say?

Comment: please show us the HTML, CSS, JS of your webpage. You should just be doing the same thing you did for your jsfiddle in order to get the map appearing on your page. But there might be other other elements on the page causing issues.

Comment: The console says, "$ not defined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message "$ not defined" indicates that jQuery is missing.

You need to add a script tag that imports jQuery. Add it in the `head` tag before all other script tags. If you don't have a version on your server, you can use one hosted by Google:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If everything else is correct, this change should fix your problem.

Comment: @mattbowlby Glad to help. Please don't forget to accept this as the chosen answer